# Cannot mount western digital hard drive. Can I clone it?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, mount, dd

I have a 1TB Western Digital USB3 external hard drive. Last day I dropped it and after that I was unable to mount it. The hard drive doesn't have a SATA connector but the circuit board translate from USB3 to a proprietary interface, so I cannot mount it in other places.

When I connect the hard drive to a Linux machine it is detected (I can see it with fdisk -l) but I cannot mount it.

So I wanted to try to clone it with dd and then try to mount the resulting image to try to recover the data. Is this possible?

I've launched the following command:

dd conv=noerror,sync if=/dev/sdc of=/myimage.img

but the copy process is terribly slow (about 200-500kb/s) so it'll take a month to copy all the 1TB. (I've tried different block sizes 64k 1M 10M but the results are very similar)

Any hint on why the copy process is so slow? What can I try to speed it up?
If dd is actually writing the image, does that mean it's actually reading the data?
Does dd show errors when it cannot read the data? (I haven't seen any errors).

Thanks

Comment: not sure why it would have a non-standard interface… would make it very expensive to manufacture. More likely, if could have an adaptor from one spec to another but most likely is it is a regular SATA underneath. That said, connecting it via a USB dock of some description will bypass any SMART lock that may be on it

Comment: I can confirm that there is no SATA interface in the My Passport drives. The USB is soldered directly to the PCB.